# Simplex Multiplier

Tags: linear-programming, simplex, lagrange-multipliers

I am reading through a book which provides an example of a linear program given by \begin{align}\min&\quad-24y_{1}-28y_{2}\\\text{s.t.}&\quad6y_{1}+10y_{2} \leq 2400\\&\quad8y_{1}+5y_{2} \leq 1600\\&\quad0\leq y_{1} \leq 500\\&\quad0\leq y_{2} \leq 100.\end{align}

The solution is $-6100{\rm(objective\ value)}, y^{\top} = (137.5,100), \pi^{\top} = (0,-3,0,-13)$ where $\pi$ is the simplex multiplier associated with the solution.

I can solve the LP to find the feasible values of $y$ but I do not understand how to find the values of the simplex multiplier. Reading some papers I found out that the simplex multiplier is calculated as:

$$\pi^{\top} = c_{B}^{\top} B^{-1}.$$

I have attempted to use this by writing this LP in the standard form but I cannot match the values of the $\pi$: \begin{align}\min&\quad C^\top X\\\text{s.t.}&\quad A\cdot X=b\\&\quad A = \begin{pmatrix}
6 & 10 & 1 & 0 & 0 &0 \\
8 & 5 & 0 & 1 & 0 &0\\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 &0\\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 &1 
\end{pmatrix}\\&\quad b = \begin{pmatrix}
2400 \\
1600 \\
500\\
100
\end{pmatrix}\\&\quad c = \begin{pmatrix}
-24 \\
-28 \\
0\\
0\\
0\\
0
\end{pmatrix}\\&\quad B = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 &0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 &0\\
0 & 0 & 1 &0\\
0 & 0 & 0 &1 
\end{pmatrix}\quad{\rm(Basis\,Matrix)}.\end{align}

Can anyone please explain how to calculate the simplex multiplier in this example?

Comment: Why negative values in your $b$ vector?

Comment: @RobPratt right it should be positive...

Comment: @RobPratt It was a typo

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is explained in this [link](http://web.mit.edu/15.053/www/AMP-Appendix-B.pdf) as:

- Simplex multipliers are essentially the shadow prices associated with a particular basic solution. Those are the *multiples* of their initial system of equations such that, when all of these equations are multiplied by their respective simplex multipliers and subtracted from the initial objective function, the coefficients of the *basic variables* are zero.
- On the other hand, the shadow prices were readily available from the final system of equations. In essence, since varying the righthand side value of a particular constraint is similar to adjusting the slack variable, it was argued that the shadow prices are the negative of the objective-function coefficients of the slack (or artificial) variables in the final system of equations.
- Similarly, the simplex multipliers at each intermediate iteration are the negative of the objective-function coefficients of these variables.

An **example** of how to calculate simplex multipliers in each intermediate iterations is given [here](http://user.engineering.uiowa.edu/%7Edbricker/Stacks_pdf8/RSM_Example1.pdf).

In your example for the final iteration of the simplex, you need to consider all the matrix operations that affected the $B$ matrix. In other words, the $B$ matrix should reflect the final basis of the simplex.

Comment: Thanks @Orguz Toragay In the worked example link that you provided, c3 is taken as zero on page 7 when calculating the reduced cost of the non basic variables x3, x4 &x5. Shouldn't this be 6 instead of zero as that would correspond to the coefficient of x3 in the objective?

Comment: @Simplyop you are right, it should be 6 and the reduced cost should be 5.8125

Comment: Thanks you for checking!

Comment: @Simplyop You are very welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are reading the example on page 185 of *Introdution of stochastic programming* by John R. Birge. After reading the explanation above by Oguz Toragay, I would like to represent my opinion on the so-called $\pi$.

In fact, $\pi$ is generated in this way. Let

$A = \left(
\begin{array}{c}
6 & 10 & 1 & 0 \\
8 & 5  & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 0  & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 1  & 0 & 0 
\end{array}
\right)
\quad
c =\left(
\begin{array}{c}
-24 \\
-28 \\
0 \\
0 
\end{array}
\right),$

Then we got $\pi = c^T \times A^{-1} = \left[ 0,-3,0,-13\right]$.

Note that there are four constraints in the origin problem, and with the optimal solution of the LP, constraints $8y_1+5y_2 \leq 1600$ and $y_2\leq100$ are tight, and the other two constraints have redundance, which leaves space to  descend. The corresponding slack variables, namely $y_3$ and $y_5$, are checked in the last step of simplex algorithm. That's why we put these two columns into matrix $A$, rather than the others. You can also observe that all items in $\pi$ are no bigger than $0$ because it is the termination condition of the simplex algorithm, and also represents the (negative) shadow price. Consequently, only $\pi_2$ and $\pi_4$ are negative because only the second and the fourth constraints are tight.